# Unable to vertical align text in navbar without anchor

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I use the following combination:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> 99999999</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have the desired output as having the phone number vertically-centered in the navbar.

However, it only works using `<a>`, if I remove it, then it goes to the top.

I have tried `<li class="navbar-btn">` but for no avail.

Is there a workaround using bootstrap css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `navbar-text` class that's all ready built in. See [Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-text).

*I included two examples in the event that you are using all the `navbar` options.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="navbar-text"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> 99999999</p>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<hr>
<h3>Full Navbar</h3>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

      <p class="navbar-text"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> 99999999</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: This is nice. Do you have any idea why the text color changes when applying `navbar-text`?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what you mean. The text color of navbar-text has a default value of color:#777 which is the same for regular list items.

Answer (score 1):

Some simple CSS can solve this by adding a unique class to the LI element : [Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/iN6099r4mz)

By inspecting the CSS in the developper console, you would have seen that an Anchor in Bootstrap's navbar had padding.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="phone-nb"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> 99999999</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.phone-nb{
    padding-top:15px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An anchor element in that context has padding, line-height and it's display adjusted which makes it appear centered. The `<li>` does not have this. If you apply `.btn` to the `<li>` it will vertically align as you wish but will center the text. You'll have to over-ride this to align it to the right.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> 99999999</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

```css
li.btn {
    text-align: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6kaq1uwf/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at bootstrap css, there's padding: 10px 15px on the anchor.

```
.nav>li>a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

You just need to add that padding to the container of the phone number if you don't want the  tag. In this case, the list tag.

```
<li class="demo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> 99999999</li>

.demo {
   padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

As for the text color change, there's a hover change from #777 to #333.

```
.demo {
  color: #777;
 }

.demo:hover {
  color: #333;
}
```

Check out this plunkr http://embed.plnkr.co/0sq4Rlc0LpcjfFtWxD3n/preview